# Round a total tax price

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-rounding

I want to round the magento tax price but I want to round the total tax amount instead rounding separately.

Something like :

```
Total Tax = Product tax amount + shipping Tax amount 

Total Tax = round(Total Tax, 2);
```

How can i achieve this ?
I don't need a tax values **separately**, only Total Tax amount should be round off then add to grand total and insert in database.

Comment: looks like you need to create a new total called for instance total_taxes and this total would read all the taxes and display the rounded sum.. If it is only a display issue, that should be reasonably easy to do, I think. But you mention storing it into the database? and therefore I dare not suggest you a solution